# Test Pylons server using Behave BDD - how to start and use server?

Tags: bdd, pylons

I've been looking around all week and can't wrap my head around how to get an instance of our pylons server started for use with the Behave BDD. Can any of you point me to an example or offer one of your own? Here's what I'm working with:

From the [Tutorial](https://behave.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) page on the Behave doc site, starting a simple server and using selenium, this is their example code for Behave's features/environment.py:

```
import threading
from wsgiref import simple_server
from selenium import webdriver
from my_application import model
from my_application import web_app

def before_all(context):
    context.server = simple_server.WSGIServer(('', 8000))
    context.server.set_app(web_app.main(environment='test'))
    context.thread = threading.Thread(target=context.server.serve_forever)
    context.thread.start()
    context.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def after_all(context):
    context.server.shutdown()
    context.thread.join()
    context.browser.quit()

def before_feature(context, feature):
    model.init(environment='test')
```

It's a start, but I have no idea how to marry this to how our 'pylowiki' flavor of pylons is started up. There is another example I've found that may provide better clues, it is [here](https://gist.github.com/517237/c8671a1001b9b1c2ff1d7d91c1c12e19417e1d57). In this example I assume I'd replace "world" with "context", but aside from that the way the server is started in this example is different from how our own environment.py starts things up.
 One last thing I think may be handy is to include the code from our current environment setup:

pylowiki/config/environment.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Pylons environment configuration"""
import os

from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from pylons import config
from pylons.error import handle_mako_error
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

import pylowiki.lib.app_globals as app_globals
import pylowiki.lib.helpers
from pylowiki.config.routing import make_map
from pylowiki.model import init_model


def load_environment(global_conf, app_conf):
    """Configure the Pylons environment via the ``pylons.config``
    object
    """
    # Pylons paths
    root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    paths = dict(root=root,
                 controllers=os.path.join(root, 'controllers'),
                 static_files=os.path.join(root, 'public'),
                 templates=[os.path.join(root, 'templates')])

    # Initialize config with the basic options
    config.init_app(global_conf, app_conf, package='pylowiki', paths=paths)

    config['routes.map'] = make_map()
    config['pylons.app_globals'] = app_globals.Globals()
    config['pylons.h'] = pylowiki.lib.helpers

    # Create the Mako TemplateLookup, with the default auto-escaping
    config['pylons.app_globals'].mako_lookup = TemplateLookup(
        directories=paths['templates'],
        error_handler=handle_mako_error,
        module_directory=os.path.join(app_conf['cache_dir'], 'templates'),
        input_encoding='utf-8', output_encoding='utf-8', default_filters=['escape'],
        imports=['from webhelpers.html import escape'])

    # Setup the SQLAlchemy database engine
    engine = engine_from_config(config, 'sqlalchemy.')
    init_model(engine)

    # CONFIGURATION OPTIONS HERE (note: all config options will override
    # any Pylons config options)
```

Answer (score 0):

behave documentation says you need environment.py in feature folder, at least, and steps folder accrdingly

https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gherkin.html#controlling-your-test-run-with-tags